# Scott's trick without the Axiom of Regularity

Tags: reference-request, set-theory

Scott's trick is a method for constructing a set as a subset of a proper class. Specifically, let $A$ be a class (proper or otherwise), and let
$$S(A)=\{x\in A:\forall y\in A,\operatorname{rank}(x)\le\operatorname{rank}(y)\}.$$

Then $S:\overline V\to V$ (where $\overline V$ represents the collection of all classes, a concept that cannot be formalized in ZF) satisfies three important properties: (1) $S(A)\subseteq A$, (2) $S(A)$ is a set, even if $A$ is not, and (3) $S(A)=\emptyset$ iff $A=\emptyset$.

I would like to generalize this construction to produce another function on $\overline V$ which satisfies the same properties, but does not require the Axiom of Regularity. The place where Regularity appears in the standard Scott's trick is in the proof of property (2), because assuming the negation of Regularity, there is a set $z$ with no rank, and a proper class of sets built from this set (say $z, \{z\}, \{\{z\}\}, \dots$ and continued by transfinite recursion), that also have no rank. Under the conventional definition of rank, $\operatorname{rank}(x)=\emptyset$ whenever $x$ has no rank, so if I take $A$ to be the class of sets containing $z$ described above, then all members of $A$ have the same rank, and thus $S(A)=A$ is also a proper class.

My question is if there is any way to construct a similar type of function that works even in such cases. Is it necessary to have a total order on all sets like $\operatorname{rank}$ in order for any such trickery to work? If so, I would guess that there is no way to do it without Regularity.

Comment: Do you assume choice, or ZF without regularity?

Comment: @AsafKaragila: do You sleep sometimes? :)

Comment: @Salech: Sometimes.

Comment: @Asaf I'll take an answer either way, although obviously I'd prefer to avoid Choice as well. Using choice, you could use cardinality as the "total order on all sets" I refer to, but for any (nonzero) cardinality, the collection of sets with that cardinality is a proper class, so you can't directly modify the procedure using $\operatorname{card}(x)$ in place of  $\operatorname{rank}(x)$.

Comment: I think it might be impossible. Atoms can be used to create models of ZFA with anti-choice, but also for producing models of ZF-Reg+Anti-regularity. I think it might be possible to show that Scott tricks can always fail in some permutation model. I'm not sure though, and I need to brush up on regularity-breaking permutations.

Comment: @Andres I would point out that neither of these facts *explicitly* contradict the statement of the problem; it only shows that $card$ and $rank$ are not viable functions for the desired property. (Edit: I see Andres removed his comment...)

Comment: (@MarioCarneiro I turned the comment into an answer.)

Answer (score 12):

*Some* assumption is needed: It is consistent with $\mathsf{ZFA}$ that there is a proper class of atoms, and there is no class function $C:V\to V$ with the property that $C(X)=C(Y)$ iff $|X|=|Y|$. This is due independently to Gauntt and to Lévy. Jech's **The axiom of choice** gives references.

On the other hand, a positive answer is possible in some situations: Assume $\mathsf{ZF}^-+\mathsf{AFA}$, that is, $\mathsf{ZF}$ with foundation replaced by the [antifoundation axiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aczel%27s_anti-foundation_axiom) due independently to Aczel and Forti-Honsell. One can prove that any model of this theory is completely determined by its well-founded part $\mathsf{WF}$, in the sense that if $(M,\in^M)$ and $(N,\in^N)$ are models of $\mathsf{ZF}^-+\mathsf{AFA}$ and $\mathsf{WF}^M\cong\mathsf{WF}^N$, then $M\cong N$.

Let me review what $\mathsf{AFA}$ says precisely. Recall that a *graph* is a pair ${\mathcal G}=(G,E)$ where $G$ is a set and $E$ is a binary relation on $G$.

A *decoration* of ${\mathcal G}$ is an assignment $\pi$ of a set to each element of $G$ in such a way that for every $x\in G$, $\pi(x)=\{\pi(y)\colon y \mathrel E x\}$.

An *apg* (accessible pointed graph) is a graph $(G,E)$ with a distinguished point $p\in G$ such that every element of $G$ is *accessible* form $p$, (i.e., there is a finite sequence $p,p_1,\dots,p_n,q$ such that $q\mathrel E p_n\mathrel E\dots\mathrel E p_1 \mathrel E p$).

A *picture* of a set $x$ is an apg ${\mathcal G}$ with distinguished node $p$ admitting a decoration $\pi$ such that $\pi(p)=x$.

Working in $\mathsf{ZF}^-$, one can prove that every set has a picture. Mostowski's collapsing theorem states that every well-founded graph has a unique decoration. This easily implies that every well-founded apg is a picture of a unique set.

> $\mathsf{AFA}$ is the statement that every graph has a unique decoration.

It follows from $\mathsf{AFA}$ that every apg is a picture of a unique set, and that non-well-founded sets exist. Moreover, every apg is equivalent to an apg on a well-founded set, where two apgs are equivalent iff they are pictures of the same set.

For references on antifoundation, and proofs of its consistency and the above claims, see

> Peter Aczel. **Non-well-founded sets**. CSLI Lecture Notes 14, Stanford University, Center for the Study of Language and Information, Stanford, CA, 1988. [MR0940014 (89j:03039)](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=0940014),

and

> Marco Forti, and Furio Honsell. *Axioms of choice and free constructions principles, I*. Bull. Soc. Math. Belg. Vol 36 (b) fasc. 1 ser. b (1984), 69-79. [MR0739920 (85f:03054)](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=739920).

Since every apg is equivalent to a well-founded apg, we can make do in $\mathsf{ZF}^-+\mathsf{AFA}$ and indirectly implement Scott's trick: Given any class $C$ consider the class $C_{\mathsf{WF}}$ of well-founded apgs that are pictures of sets in $C$. If $C$ is non-empty, select a subset of $C_{\mathsf{WF}}$ using Scott's trick. The collection of corresponding sets is a subset of the class $C$.

Comment: The lack of cardinal representatives was transferred to ZF by Pincus. He later wrote a paper about the consistency of representatives as well.

Comment: The citation to Pincus paper in my previous comment is David Pincus, **[Cardinal representatives](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF02760841).** *Israel J. Math.* **18** (1974), 321-344 ([MR366666](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=366666)).

Comment: This is a well-written answer with good references, but it discusses slightly different questions than the one I posed, so I can't award the bounty just yet. If I understand you correctly, though, you are saying that a Scott's trick can be implemented in ZF-reg+(Aczel's antifoundation)?

Comment: Mario: The Gaunt-Lévy result shows that in ZFA, "functions" like S do not necessarily exist, even if we restrict to classes that are cardinalities, $\overline V'=\{\{B\mid |B|=|A|\}\mid A\in V\}$. The ZF-+AFA result shows that a "function" like S exists in this theory.

Comment: (Of course, if there is a proper class of "indiscernible" atoms, the class of atoms already shows that S does not exist, but the Gaunt-Lévy result shows that we cannot "repair" this, even if we remove requirement (1) that $S(C)\subset C$ for each class $C$.)

Comment: I don't understand your last statement. All three conditions I have stated are essential; if you drop (1), the function $S(C)=\{\emptyset\}$ if $C\ne\emptyset$ and $S(C)=\emptyset$ otherwise will satisfy the other two conditions trivially.

Comment: @MarioCarneiro Sorry, didn't mean to be confusing. You are not quite "dropping" $(1)$ altogether. Rather, you are replacing $S(C)\subset C$ with the requirement $(1)'$ that $C\mapsto S(C)$ assigns to each cardinality $C$ a set (which does not need to be a subset of $S(C)$) in a $1$-$1$ fashion. Note that cardinalities are disjoint classes, so your requirement $(1)$ implies $(1)'$.

Comment: I just got Jech, and have been reading through the referenced sections, but I feel the need to point out that $\sf{ZFA}$, as defined in Jech, modifies extensionality so that it does not apply to atoms, even though the quantifiers range over sets and atoms alike. Doesn't this mean that it is not a valid model of $\sf{ZF}-\sf{Reg}$? Other than that, I think I understand how the cardinality result excludes the possibility of a Scott's trick in $\sf{ZFA}$, and thus also in $\sf{ZF}-\sf{Reg}$, assuming my complaint is resolved.

Comment: $\mathsf{ZFA}$ satisfies regularity (appropriately stated; every non-empty set $x$ either contains as an element an atom or a set disjoint from $x$), the issue comes from having the collection of atoms being a proper class rather than a set. But yes, $\mathsf{ZFA}$ does not imply $\mathsf{ZF}$ in its usual formulation, because of the presence of atoms. There is a standard tool for transfering results from $\mathsf{ZFA}$ to $\mathsf{ZF}$ (the embedding theorems), but it does not apply in this case.

Comment: My interpretation of your comment is that there is still some space for a proper proof or counterexample, since so far your proof requires a different version of extensionality, so I am stating for the record that I don't yet consider this question fully resolved, although you have put some work into your answer and the bounty period is almost out, so you can have this bounty.

Comment: How many Quine atoms are there in AFA? It seems like there should be exactly one, but consider the apg $G=\{0,1,2,3,4\}$; $0\in 0\in2,3$; $1\in 1\in3$; $2,3\in 4$. This is an apg with $4$ at the top, and represents a set $4\mapsto\{\{x\},\{x,y\}\}$ where $x,y$ are Quine atoms interpreting $0,1$. We must have $x\ne y$ because $0\in 2$ and $1\notin 2$, so the set $\{x\}$ interpreting $2$ must have $x$ and not $y$ in it. But then $x$ and $y$ are distinct deorations for the apg $G=\{0\}$, $0\in 0$, and AFA is inconsistent. What gives?

Comment: Hi @Mario, you are right that there is exactly one. This means that in your example, we actually have $0=1$, $2=3$ (so $1\in 2$).

Comment: But doesn't the definition of decoration imply $\pi(x)\in\pi(y)\iff x\,E\,y$, which would mean that $1\notin2$ in the graph should force $\pi(1)\notin\pi(2)$?

Comment: What do you mean by no such class function exists? ZFA can't even describe the statement that no such class function exists. Sometimes in ZF, people say "the class of all sets is proper" when they really mean "there is no set of all sets." When you say "It's consistent that no such class function exists," do you mean it's not provable in NBG with urelements without regularity that such a class function exists?

Comment: @Timothy You should read the references I mentioned to see precisely what I meant.