# Relation between Axiom of Foundation and Axiom of Extensionality

Tags: set-theory

My question is related to this question ([Meaning of the Axiom of regularity (foundation)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/825540/meaning-of-the-axiom-of-regularity-foundation/825577#825577)).

Why wouldn't $p\neq q$ be ruled out without axiom of foundation? And how does Axiom of foundation helps in rolling it out?
Also I appreciate if someone tells me why the first program of @Asaf's answer in mentions question hold which is.
"Such sets $(x=\{ x\} )$are sometimes called Quine Atoms. And indeed if x,y are two different Quine atoms, then $x\neq y$ because $x\notin y $ and $y \in y$ (and vice versa) "?

I am fairly new to this topic, therefore I am sorry if my question sounds naive.

Answer (score 1):

It's not that $p\neq q$ is ruled out by the axiom of regularity. It is the existence of a set of the form $x=\{x\}$, or a *Quine atom*, altogether which is ruled out.

The problem is that we often think about sets as "defined by a formula" or "a property". So the property $x=\{x\}$ is something that if two sets satisfy, we cannot distinguish them "as easily", and we need to more or less require them to be distinct axiomatically.

Comment: Thank for your answer. A couple of things I want to clear out for myself:   1. Am I right that thinking about sets having "a property" runs us into the problem of mixing sets with proper classes?   2. Can we even have $x=\{ x\}$ as set? A set containing itself!

Comment: To the proposer: None of the axioms of ZFC (Zermelo-Frankel- Choice) actually mentions "sets". And none of the axioms defines "$\in$".  It is just a binary-relation symbol. Other binary relations can be reflexive, e.g. $ x\leq x.$